# How do I find the closest match in a CommCare Lookup Table?

Tags: commcare

Is it possible to lookup the closest value (equal or less than) to a particular question using a Lookup Table in CommCare?

Example:
My table has values 5, 6.35, 42.8, 136. I want an input of 6 to return 5, 6.35 to return 6.35, 48 to return 42.8, and 135 to return 42.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use `<=` in a filter in combination with `max` to achieve this affect.

The xpath might look something like this

```
max(instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry[value <= target_value]/value)
```

That will give you the maximum value less than `target_value`. If what you wanted was the entire row in the table that has that value, you can then do a lookup on that value—i.e. find the row that has the value that is the maximum value less than `target_value`:

```
instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry/value[value =
    max(instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry[value <= target_value]/value)]
```

Comment: In addition if you wanted the "closest" value, you could use the same approach except with the addition of "min" and greater than: `min(instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry[value >= target_value]/value)`. Once you have both those values, you can easily determine which one is closer to the target value.

Comment: Your answers definitely led me in the right direction (thanks!), but it turned out to actually be easiest to duplicate the lookup column and create a second column staggered by 1 space, so that I could get rid of the min():     'instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry[/data/target_value >= min_vale][/data/target_value < max_value]/min_value'.

This allowed me to easily grab any other value in the lookup table: 
'instance('myentrys')/myentry_list/myentry[/data/target_value >= min_value][/data/target_value < max_value]/other_column'.